# Application.Ontime works when called from a sub but not from a function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

Please take a look at the code:

```
 '' the sub I can call manually to see if the whole thing works
 '' (and it does)
Sub ManualSubTest() 
    Call SendNotification 
End Sub 

 '' this is the function I need to refer to from the IF formula
 '' when I do, Ontime does not work
Function SendNotification() 
    SendNotificationAction 
    Debug.Print ("first step...") 
End Function 

 '' the main sub that will perfom the action
Private Sub SendNotificationAction() 
     '' do something here
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"), "SendNotificationCallback" 
End Sub 

 '' this is the callback that normally triggers the action code again
Private Sub SendNotificationCallback() 
     ''SendNotificationAction
     '' or
     ''Call SendNotificationAction
    Debug.Print ("OK!") 
End Sub
```

Everything works fine when I call the `ManualSubTest` sub manually from the macro menu. As you can see, all it does is trigger the `SendNotification` function. In the end result I see the "OK!" message in the Immediate Window.

But I need that `SendNotification` function to work when I call it from a worksheet IF condition, i.e. `=If($A$1=1; SendNotification(); "")`, and for some reason it does not. It just stops right before the [Ontime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221399%28office.12%29.aspx) call.

What's the difference? Do the [Functions vs. Subroutines limitations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787) apply? Please help. Thanks

Comment: x-posted: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/758000-something-wrong-application-ontime-does-not-get-scheduled-when-function.html, http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=186245

Comment: Yes, [Functions vs. Subroutines limitations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787) apply. You cannot do these things from functions called from sheets. Call this function in some other way and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

try to add a

```
 application.enableevents=true
```

in the function, just before the onaction